# Add a constant value to a xmm register in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, x87

How would I add `1` or `2` to the register `xmm0` (double)?

I can do it like this, but sure there must be an easier way:

```
movsd xmm0, [ecx]

xor eax, eax
inc eax
cvtsi2sd xmm1, eax
addsd xmm0, xmm1

movsd [ecx], xmm0
```

Also would it be possible to do this with the floating point x87 instructions?

This doesn't work for me:

```
fld dword ptr [ecx]
fld1
faddp
fstp dword ptr [ecx]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can keep a constant in memory or in another register:

```
_1      dq      1.0
```

and

```
addsd   xmm1,[_1]
```

or

```
movsd   xmm0,[_1]
addsd   xmm1,xmm0
```

If you are on x64, you can do this:

```
mov     rax,1.0
movq    xmm0,rax
addsd   xmm1,xmm0
```

or use the stack if the type mismatch bothers you:

```
mov     rax,1.0
push    rax
movsd   xmm0,[rsp]
pop     rax
addsd   xmm1,xmm0
```

As for the x87 code, `double`s are `qwords`, not `dwords`.

Comment: `movsd   xmm0,[esp]` or `movsd   xmm0,[rsp]`?

Comment: The suggestion to use the stack is terrible anyway, and doesn't avoid the surprising use of a `double` constant as an operand to `mov r64, imm64`.  If you want to avoid that, suggest `mov eax, 1` / `cvtsi2sd xmm0, eax`

Comment: You can also generate `1.0` in an xmm register with only a 3 instructions, IIRC (starting with `pcmpeqw` to generate all-ones).  Agner Fog's [Optimizing Assembly](http://agner.org/optimize)

Comment: See [Use of NASM's \_\_?float?\_\_ macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66476230) for `mov rax, __?float64?__(1.0)`.  YASM accepts `mov rax, 1.0` but NASM doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
vpcmpeqq  xmm1,xmm1,xmm1          ; xmm1 = [ -1 | -1 | -1 | -1 ] as ints
vmovsd    xmm0,dword ptr [ecx]    ; xmm0 = VALUE as int
vsubsd    xmm0,xmm0,xmm1          ; xmm0 = VALUE - (-1) = VALUE + 1
```

The above should be

```
vpcmpeqq  xmm1,xmm1,xmm1          ; xmm1 = [ -1 | -1 | -1 | -1 ] as ints
vmovd     xmm0,dword ptr [ecx]    ; xmm0 = VALUE as int
vpsubd    xmm0,xmm0,xmm1          ; xmm0 = VALUE - (-1) = VALUE + 1
```

for integer increment by 1 and

```
vpcmpeqq  xmm1,xmm1,xmm1          ; xmm1 = [ -1 | -1 ] as quads
vmovsd    xmm0,dword ptr [ecx]    ; xmm0 = VALUE as double
vcvtdq2pd xmm1,xmm1               ; xmm1 = [ -1.0 | -1.0 ] as doubles
vsubsd    xmm0,xmm0,xmm1          ; xmm0 = VALUE - (-1.0) = VALUE + 1.0
```

for double increment by 1.0

Comment: Could you specify what CPU extensions are needed for these AVX/SIMD instructions?

Comment: This doesn't seem like it'll work.  You're going to subtract the double-precision float with bit pattern `0xffffffffffffffff` and that's a NaN, not -1.

Comment: You're missing a `vcvtdq2pd xmm1,xmm1` int -> FP conversion to get double `-1.0`.  Or probably a single left shift of the `-1ULL` could create the right bit-pattern, with contiguous bits set at the top.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thank you all for pointing out my mistakes. I corrected them so I hope It is ok now. All instructions are AVX.