# Use of NASM's __?float?__ macros

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86-64, nasm

The NASM manual talks about these macros, but it doesn't really explain how to use them as far as I can see. [Section 3.4.6](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.6) states:

> Floating-point constants are acceptable only as arguments to `DB`, `DW`, `DD`, `DQ`, `DT`, and `DO`, or as arguments to the special operators `__?float8?__`, `__?float16?__`, `__?bfloat16?__`, `__?float32?__`, `__?float64?__`, `__?float80m?__`, `__?float80e?__`, `__?float128l?__`, and `__?float128h?__`

At first, I thought this was to use floating-point constants outside the data section. But when I tried `mov xmm0, __?float32?__(1.23)`, I got an "Invalid combination of opcode and operands" error. Eventually, I saw that `foo: dd __?float32?__(1.23)` works. This feels strange to me though; if you can do `dd 1.23` directly, what is the point of these macros? One possibility could be if maybe you need to define, for example, a single-precision float in a quadword. Is this truly the only use for these macros, or am I using them wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These macros don't change the fact that x86 has no instructions with an immediate source and an XMM or x87 destination.  Remember, NASM is an assembler, not a compiler.

The use-cases include the rare case where you want to mov-immediate an FP bit-pattern into an integer register, like **`mov eax, __?float32?__(1.23)`**.  After which you might do `movd xmm0, eax`, or even AVX-512 `vpbroadcastd xmm0, eax`.

Normally compilers load FP data into registers from constants in memory (and that's usually a good option), but it's not the only way to go about it.

(AVX-512 makes immediates more attractive because of efficient broadcast, but you can broadcast from memory too with only AVX1, or SSE3 `movddup` for a double.  Compilers still use memory constants for scalar float, and that's still generally what I'd recommend unless profiling shows lots of data cache misses on that, and not a lot of I-cache misses in your program in general.)

Or for something like `if (x) *fp_ptr = 1.0;`, you might want to mov-immediate to memory like `mov dword [rdi], __?float32?__(1.0)`.

Another use-case could possibly be in a [NASM `%if` conditional assembly directive](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html), or some other case where you want an FP bit-pattern as an integer value that *isn't* a `dd`.  Although nothing sensible comes to mind.

Or as part of an expression like `__?float32?__(1.0) >> 23` to get the exponent (and sign bit) of a float constant you want to use for something.

---

For the record:

```
mov eax, __?float32?__(1.23)
mov eax, __?float32?__(1.0) >> 23
mov dword [rdi], __?float32?__(1.0)
```

assembled with `nasm -felf64 foo.asm` and disassembled with `objdump -drwC -Mintel foo.o`

```
   0:   b8 a4 70 9d 3f          mov    eax,0x3f9d70a4
   5:   b8 7f 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x7f
   a:   c7 07 00 00 80 3f       mov    DWORD PTR [rdi],0x3f800000
```

---

Related:

- [NASM: why must __float32__(1.5) be used for floating point literals instead of just 1.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925432/nasm-why-must-float32-1-5-be-used-for-floating-point-literals-instead-of-j) - NASM uses a different parser for `dd` / `dq`, where seeing a `.` in a number implies floating-point.  That's why `dd 1.5` works, `mov eax, 1.5` doesn't (yet).

Older NASM [documented](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.10.09/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.6) `__float32__(1.23)`; that still assembles, but the NASM manual currently only documents the form with `?` used in this answer.  I think that makes it not a valid NASM preprocessor macro/token, in case that's relevant.  And not a valid symbol name.

Comment: Ah yes, I just tried it with `eax` and it worked. Pretty stupid of me not to try that in hindsight... I hadn't realized you couldn't put literals at all into `xmm` registers (I'm trying to learn vectors and SIMD). Either way, you have given me the answer I've been looking for.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1: Also keep in mind that `mov` can *never* have an XMM destination (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov), so that's another thing to check on next time an instruction won't assemble.  Instructions that can write an XMM register include `movd xmm, r/m32`, `movdqu xmm, xmm/mem`, `vbroadcastss xmm, xmm/mem`

Comment: Ah ok, I hadn't realized that. I'll look up those instructions, and thanks for the link.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1: Updated my answer with another plausible and maybe-interesting use-cases: mov-immediate to memory, or doing further constant-expression math on the float32 bit-pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I hadn't thought about using them for that, especially with the bit-shifting. Interesting.