# Replace `movss xmm0, cs:dword_5B27420` with `movss xmm0, immediate`

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, sse, immediate-operand

I have a linux .so file in Ida Pro and I have the following instruction:

```
movss   xmm0, cs:dword_5B27420
```

Is it possible to move a fixed value into `xmm0` using the same or less number of bytes than that instruction?

The instruction bytes are:

```
F3 0F 10 05 C8 BB A 00
```

I want to do something like:

```
movss   xmm0, 0.3
```

Comment: I don't think there's opcode for that. However, nothing prevents you from putting the desired value into some unused memory address and modifying the load appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in fewer bytes; if you don't have room here, you'd have to jump somewhere else and then back, or just change the RIP-relative address to load a different constant from somewhere else.  (e.g. from padding between two functions, or spare space in .rodata or .data if there is any.)

There is no mov-immediate to XMM registers, and `mov eax, __?float32?__(0.3)` (5 bytes) / `movd xmm0, eax` (4 bytes) would take more total bytes.  (That's [NASM syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66476230/use-of-nasms-float-macros) for the integer value that is the bit-pattern for the given FP constant.  Some assemblers may allow `mov eax, 0.3`, in case that's ever useful.)

Ways other than immediates to construct FP constants include `pcmpeqd xmm0,xmm0` (4 bytes) and then shifting or doing other things (like `pabsd`) with the all-ones bit patterns.  But that's at least 2 instructions unless you want a NaN.  (See [Agner Fog's optimizing asm guide](https://www.agner.org/optimize/), and [What are the best instruction sequences to generate vector constants on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085059/what-are-the-best-instruction-sequences-to-generate-vector-constants-on-the-fly))

`0.3f` is not a simple constant you could materialize even in 3 instructions from `0xffffffff` with left and right shifts, unlike `1.0f` for example.  (But that's still three instructions, 4 and 5 bytes each to construct set1(1.0f))

`cmpps` is SSE1 non-scalar so it has a smaller opcode than `pcmpeqd` (no mandatory prefixes, just `0f c2`), but isn't any smaller overall because it needs an immediate for the compare predicate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242872/discussion-on-answer-by-peter-cordes-replace-movss-xmm0-csdword-5b27420-with-i).